# Azure blob storage and container permissions

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have one Azure storage account with several containers, where I have some guest users who will be logging into the portal, but they should have `read`/`write` access to the specific containers. These guest users should not have `delete` permissions.

I have gone through so many articles but never succeed.

Is there any way where I can achieve this?

Answer (score 8):

To give a specific container permission, you can do this followings:

Find your container, select Access Policy under the settings blade, and click Add Policy. Select the permissions which you want to give this specific container. Also, public access level is container level.

[image]

You can get more details from [Manage anonymous read access to containers and blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-manage-access-to-resources)

In addition, there is a preview version of [managing access rights to Azure storage account with RBAC roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/ca-es/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-rbac). For the container scope, assign the Storage Blob Data Reader (Preview) role to a user. But it is intended for non-production use only.

Comment: But this will give access to all containers inside the blob right, not the specific one?

Comment: @akshayvithalkar  You are correct, i miss the specific one. please check my update.

Comment: @NancyXiong Do  you know what the different between Add, Create and Write Permissions?  Can't find it in the documentation.

Comment: @snerting you could refer to this, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas#permissions-for-a-blob

Comment: Is there a way to limit access to a specific container within a storage account using a SAS or RBAC (or both ?!)